# Trying to figure out URL dispatcher for sluggale URLs like stackoverflow

Tags: python, slug, tornado

I'm using the Tornado framework (Python).  I have the sluggable URLs working.  But I have 3 different entries in the URL dispatcher.  I was wondering if someone could help me transform it into one line.

This is what I have:

```
(r"/post/([0-9]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+", SpotHandler),
(r"/post/([0-9]+)/", SpotHandler),
(r"/post/([0-9]+)", SpotHandler),
```

I want it so that the following URLs all go to the same place.

http://domain.com/post/14

http://domain.com/post/14/

http://domain.com/post/14/any-text-it-doesnt-matter-what-it-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(r"/post/([0-9]+)/?[a-zA-Z_]*", SpotHandler),

"?" means previous thing can be there but need not be.
"*" means zero or more

Comment: @TylerW @mawimawi @zed_0xff what about this URL: `http://domain.com/post/14something` or `http://domain.com/post/14/something/` ~~ @TylerW what about if it's supposed to be `http://domain.com/post/14/something` and they goto `http://domain.com/post/14/otherthing`? I'm guessing that's not a business domain problem here...

Comment: Correct.  My site doesn't use the end sting at all.  Just the number after /post/.  So /post/14/string1 and /post/14/string2 can go to the same thing.

Comment: Keep in mind that the path can legally contain unicode, which your regex won't match, if that matters to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
r"/post/([0-9]+)(?:/[a-zA-Z_-]+|/)?"
```